# Somar valores de uma api json e exibir resultados // React JS

Tags: javascript, react, react-hooks

Minha api json:

```
{
  "chamado": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "numeroChamado": 435689,
      "sistema": "xx",
      "requerenteChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "tecnicoChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "statusChamado": "Processando",
      "valorBoleto": 350,
      "mesChamado": "Janeiro"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "numeroChamado": 778854,
      "sistema": "xx",
      "requerenteChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "tecnicoChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "statusChamado": "Pendente",
      "valorBoleto": 250,
      "mesChamado": "Janeiro"
    }]
}
```

Preciso obter os valores de valorBoleto e somar todos de acordo com o mesChamado.
Somar todos de Janeiro e assim por diante.
Estou utilizando React Js(Hooks).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um `reduce` para montar um objeto no formato `mesChamado: totalDoMes`, primeiramente você precisa extrair os chamados da resposta que você obteve da api:

```
const api = {
  "chamado": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "numeroChamado": 435689,
      "sistema": "xx",
      "requerenteChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "tecnicoChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "statusChamado": "Processando",
      "valorBoleto": 350,
      "mesChamado": "Janeiro"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "numeroChamado": 778854,
      "sistema": "xx",
      "requerenteChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "tecnicoChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "statusChamado": "Pendente",
      "valorBoleto": 250,
      "mesChamado": "Janeiro"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "numeroChamado": 778854,
      "sistema": "xx",
      "requerenteChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "tecnicoChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "statusChamado": "Pendente",
      "valorBoleto": 180,
      "mesChamado": "Fevereiro"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "numeroChamado": 435689,
      "sistema": "xx",
      "requerenteChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "tecnicoChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "statusChamado": "Pendente",
      "valorBoleto": 250,
      "mesChamado": "Fevereiro"
    }
  ]
}

const { chamado } = api
```

Após ter o array com os dados basta fazer um `reduce`:

```
const valorTotal = chamado.reduce((total, value) => {
  return {
    ...total,
    [value.mesChamado]: value.valorBoleto + (total[value.mesChamado] ?? 0)
  }
}, {})
```

Basicamente estou passando uma `function` como primeiro paramêtro, recuperando o valor acumulado que chamei de `total`, e o valor atual que chamei de `value` e como segundo paramêtro indico qual será o valor inicial que será atribuido a total, a partir dai podemos montar nosso objeto com a chave sendo o mês do chamado e o valor sendo a soma entre o valor do boleto e o total já acumulado.

```js
const api = {
  "chamado": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "numeroChamado": 435689,
      "sistema": "xx",
      "requerenteChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "tecnicoChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "statusChamado": "Processando",
      "valorBoleto": 350,
      "mesChamado": "Janeiro"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "numeroChamado": 778854,
      "sistema": "xx",
      "requerenteChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "tecnicoChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "statusChamado": "Pendente",
      "valorBoleto": 250,
      "mesChamado": "Janeiro"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "numeroChamado": 778854,
      "sistema": "xx",
      "requerenteChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "tecnicoChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "statusChamado": "Pendente",
      "valorBoleto": 180,
      "mesChamado": "Fevereiro"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "numeroChamado": 435689,
      "sistema": "xx",
      "requerenteChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "tecnicoChamado": "xxx.xxx",
      "statusChamado": "Pendente",
      "valorBoleto": 250,
      "mesChamado": "Fevereiro"
    }
  ]
}

const { chamado } = api

const valorTotal = chamado.reduce((total, value) => {
  return {
    ...total,
    [value.mesChamado]: value.valorBoleto + (total[value.mesChamado] ?? 0)
  }
}, {})

console.log(valorTotal)
```

Comment: muito obrigado, funciona quando chamo no console, mas quando chamo na pagina não funciona, por que?